# Hiding AutoSuggestBox in NavigationView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `NavigationView` control with an `AutoSearchBox` displayed:

```
<NavigationView Style="{StaticResource CompactNavigationViewStyle}" 
      x:Name="NavigationView" OpenPaneLength="280" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
      AlwaysShowHeader="False">
<NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
    <AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find" Width="235" 
      x:Name="SearchTxt" QuerySubmitted="OnSearch" />
</NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
```

For some page I don't want to show the `Search` (i.e `SettingPage`), so on `NavigationView` `ItemInvoked` event I added this code:

```
private void NavigationView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender,
   NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    if (!args.IsSettingsInvoked)
    {
        string tag = (args.InvokedItem as string);
        switch(tag)
        {
            case "settingpage":
            case "exportpage":
            SearchTxt.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            break;
            default:
            SearchTxt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            break;
        }

        // Code to load new page to Frame here
    }
}
```

The `AutoSuggestBox` is hidden from `NavigationView`, but the `Search` icon still displayed on Compact mode, how to hide this icon too?

[image: NavigationView & AutoSuggestBox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are looking for does not appear to be possible with the `NavigationView` control. This is relatively new control, however, so Microsoft may be updating it in the future.

For the technical reason, setting a value to the `AutoSuggestBox` property does more than just add an `AutoSuggestBox` to the `NavigationView`; it also changes some other internals of the `NavigationView` (such as the one specifying showing that search icon when the pane is collapsed).

The `AutoSuggestBox` property is an optional property, and designed to contain a search box "to allow for app-level search". This suggests that it is designed to be always visible across the entire app when present (although I could see a reasonable argument being made for having it disabled on certain pages). But simply, it looks like this is a use case the control is not designed for.

As for some ideas for work-arounds:

**Option 1**

The one place you can freely put whatever content you want is the `NavigationView.Footer`. You can implement something like the above code, and then adjust the `StackPanel`'s visibility property.

The main downside to this option, of course, is that the footer is stuck at the bottom, which may be an odd place to put a search bar. You also will need to give the `StackPanel` some visual styling to mimic the hover and click effects on the rest of the `NavigationView`.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            Margin="10">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuIconStyle}"
               Text="&#xE094;"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuItemTextStyle}"
               Text="Home"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

And then the supporting styles for the `Page.Resources`, so that the above bindings work (you may need to play around with the numbers for the margins and font sizes, but this looked good for me):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="HamburgerMenuIconStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="HamburgerMenuItemTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,0,20,0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

**Option 2**

You can implement your own `NavigationView`, using a `SplitView`. This is actually not too difficult, and there is even a fantastic tutorial in the following link (which I have used for several personal projects): https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners-14541?l=4DLgEZ0qB_5705244527. Specifically see Video #22, if the link doesn't open that one.

Implementing your own works well enough for visual looks, and for navigational functionality. Unfortunately, however, the more advanced features in the built-in `NavigationView` control are considerably more time-consuming to implement, such as the built-in "Back" navigation support, and the built-in fluent design styling. You can wrap this into a `UserControl` or a custom Control, so that you can reuse it in other projects, but the initial time investment will still be high.

It is worth noting that the requirements you are imposing on your users by using a `NavigationView` in the first place should be considered (if you have not done so already):

- The `NavigationView` was introduced in the Fall Creator's Update, so any users must have a version newer than that. Somewhere around 90% of users who have Windows 10 do, so this is pretty safe for most people.
- The Back navigation functionality of the `NavigationView` was introduced even more recently, specifically in v10.0.17110.0. This is still in Windows Insider, and not generally released yet (I believe), so this functionality specifically may not be a good choice for a larger audience yet. The reason I point this out, is that to reach a larger audience, you would need to implement the back functionality yourself anyway, so the barrier to writing your own `NavigationView` may not be as high as it seems.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
<NavigationViewItem
    x:Name="NaviSearchItem"
    Icon="Find"
    Visibility="Collapsed" />
<NavigationViewItem x:Name="NaviSearchBarItem">
    <AutoSuggestBox
        x:Name="NaviSearchBar"
        PlaceholderText="Search"
        QueryIcon="Find" />
</NavigationViewItem>
```

You can surround the `AutoSuggestBox` with `NavigationViewItem` and place the Search Button above it. Then you need to set the visibility of `NaviSearchBarItem` instead of the `AutoSuggestBox`. This hides the `AutoSuggestBox` perfectly.

However, there is a tiny issue with this solution. When you click on the `NaviSearchBarItem` to open the Pane, the animation of tab (a blue pipe that indicates the selected item) will still slide to the `NaviSearchBarItem`, and then it disappears. The ideal solution should be that the blue indicator still remain on the original item. I don't know how to fix this.